# How to fix "RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime."

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am having a problem with running my Python programs after installing a new package. The error message that I am getting states:

> RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ("[Location of file]") fails to pass a sanity check  due to a bug in the windows
> runtime.See this issue for more information: [URL]

I use VS code.

Comment: Tip for next time: If you search for, e.g. " fails to pass a sanity check  due to a bug in the windows runtime" - there are literally 25 questions that have been asked recently about the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open the command prompt.
2. Type `pip install --upgrade numpy==1.19.3`

The current numpy version is having some bugs.
You can use `--upgrade` to upgrade and downgrade packages

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when using some Numpy versions. So uninstalling your current version and installing 1.19.3 will work.

1. sudo pip uninstall numpy
2. pip install --upgrade numpy==1.19.3